# how to optimise two for loops in java

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, data-structures

Is there any way to optimise these for loops ?

```
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++) 
            {
                for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++) 
                {
                    if(i < j) 
                    {
                        if(a[i]+a[j] >= l && a[i]+a[j] <= r)
                            count++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is not optimal here?

Comment: What do you mean "optimize"? Are you trying to save space, time, or computational complexity? Have you benchmarked to see if this is your actual problem? Asking us to "optimize" your code is like asking an auto mechanic to "improve" your engine and then walking away. It can mean a lot of things, and often the part you're looking at isn't even the right part.

Comment: The `if(i < j)` seems useless, since `i` will always be smaller than `j` in this code. You can also store `a[i]+a[j]` in a variable to not compute it two times.

Comment: I want to save time as I am getting TLE

Comment: first I would say that `if(i < j)` is redundant, because j starts at `i + 1` and will always be greater than i

Comment: still getting Time limit exceeded

Comment: is the array `a` sorted in an ascending order? then you can exit the loop if `a[i]+a[j] > r`

Comment: no, its not sorted

Comment: in that case, I don't see any optimization you can do, because there is no relationship between an element and the next. Maybe the extra costs of sorting allow for less looping. are the elements strictly positive?

Comment: If this is for a coding challenge and you're getting time limited exceeded, then you don't need to optimize the algorithm; you need to find a new algorithm. There's probably some mathematical trick to the actual problem that simplifies it, and that context is lost when showing just the two for loops.

Comment: yes, it is strictly increasing

Comment: wait, if it is strictly increasing, then it must be sorted already

Answer (score 1):

It depends what these 2 loops do.

Imagine that these 2 loops are traversing a 2 dimensional table.
If you need to find the sum of all the elements of the table this cannot be optimised.  You have to traverse all the elements line by line.

If you want to find a specific value of the AI for example... that you have to traverse again and again the same values, in this case you can optimize by not traversing the same values you did before.
For example if these values of the table are values of a tree structure, and you traverse a branch, after you don't have to traverse the same branch. You can prune it as we say.

With this way you optimize your searching in the table using the loops.